# How do I add sort to column headings in a caxlsx Pivot Table

Tags: axlsx, caxlsx

I've got a pivot table (see code below) where the source raw data is already sorted by client, year, and month. This means the row headings (A=Client, B=Year) are automatically sorted with the data, but the column headings (C2:N2=months of the year) become random ordered.

```
    package.workbook.add_worksheet(name: "Samples Pivot") do |sheet|
      data_range = "A1:E#{@raw_client_data_total_rows}"
      sheet.add_pivot_table "A1:F1", data_range do |pivot_table|
        pivot_table.data_sheet = package.workbook.worksheets.first
        pivot_table.rows = %w[Client Year]
        pivot_table.columns = %w[Month]
        pivot_table.data = %w[Count]
      end
    end
```

If I open the spreadsheet in Excel, I can click on the auto-filter arrow on C1, which pops up an auto-filter dialog, and then I can manually sort the column headings by selecting "Ascending" and sort by "Month".

[image: Screenshot of pivot table column sort]

So is there a way to add this sort in caxlsx? I don't see any `auto_filter` attribute in [`PivotTable`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx/PivotTable).

Answer (score 0):

At the time of the question, that option wasn't available yet.

Feature implemented in [PR#143](https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx/pull/143)